# PdfSharp concurrent PdfReader.Open usage

Tags: c#, concurrency, pdfsharp

I am writing a program that will take an existing PDF template file, copy it to a new directory with a new name, open the new file with `PdfSharp`, make some edits, then save and close it. This process needs to run in bulk, and so to improve processing speed I'm using an `ActionBlock` to fire off multiple tasks in parallel. Each parallel task might, for example, create 100 pdf files each.

**The issue I'm seeing** is that each task is successfully starting to create files and then stopping partway through with no exceptions, errors or any other indication of a problem occurring. The `ActionBlock` isn't reaching a Completion status either.

Here's a simplified example of my code to illustrate and re-create the issue generically:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int maxDegreeOfParallelism = 4;

    // Create an ActionBlock<int> that performs some work.
    var workerBlock = new ActionBlock<int>((JobNo) =>
    {
        string SourceTemplateFilePath = "C:\\Test\\Template" + JobNo.ToString() + ".pdf";

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            string DestinationFilePath = "C:\\Test\\Folder" + JobNo.ToString() + "\\Job" + JobNo.ToString() + "_" + i.ToString() + ".pdf";
            File.Copy(SourceTemplateFilePath, DestinationFilePath);
            using (PdfDocument document = PdfReader.Open(DestinationFilePath, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Modify))
            {
                // manipulate pdf content & save changes
                document.Close();
            }
        }
    },
    // Specify a maximum degree of parallelism.
    new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
    {
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = maxDegreeOfParallelism,
        BoundedCapacity = maxDegreeOfParallelism
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < maxDegreeOfParallelism; i++)
    {
        if (workerBlock.Post(i))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Posted job to actionblock..." + i.ToString());
        }
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

I've attached a screenshot of the folder structure I've contrived to demo this example.
[image]

The above code runs 4 tasks, each copying a template pdf file (which is about 1MB in size) 100 times, with an incrementing file name. Each task takes a different Template file to copy to prove there are no conflicts over the file to copy. Once the file is copied, it's opened with `PdfReader.Open` before immediately closing it with `Close()`.

This code runs without issue in debug on my local machine but once published and run in release, it will produce a few of the files (each task might get as far as creating between 20-60, it differs each attempt) before pausing with no error thrown etc.

If I remove the entire `PdfReader.Open` `using` statement, the application runs to completion without pausing. If I replace the `PdfReader.Open` with a standard .NET `FileStream` and open the file stream, and close it within the `using` statement, it also runs to completion without pausing.

My current conclusion is that something about the `PdfReader.Open` method is creating a lock of some sort that's resulting in a deadlock. Has anyone got any prior experience with concurrency using PdfSharp? Am I doing something obviously wrong here?

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

### Update

On a whim I decided to re-write my example code into a .NET Core 5.0 console app rather than the .NET Framework 4.7.2 version I've been testing so far. The issue I've described does not present itself in this Core version, only the Framework one. Very odd behaviour given I'm using the exact same `PdfSharp` nuget package etc. so wouldn't expect this to make a difference.

I'm investigating whether there's any other factors at play in my workplace, speaking with server admins to see if security software is interfering with the normal running of the application etc. but nothing conclusive yet.

I just thought I'd share my findings for anyone else (however unlikely it might be) that encounters a similar problem.

Thanks to those that provided comments.

Comment: PDFsharp should work as long as there is only a single thread dealing with a particular `PdfDocument` object at any time. Handling multiple documents at the same time should work under this precondition. But your use case is unusual and maybe there is a lock missing somewhere in PDFsharp where global tables are used. Usually documents are created from scratch and locks have been added to deal with that case.

Comment: @IlikedtheoldStackOverflow the idea behind the use case is to take a template pdf which was manually created with a large number of form fields and prefill them from another source of data. Then save the filled in copy to a drive. I'd seen other posts about concurrency with creating a document from scratch as you say, so I looked around for ways to test this theory out and not use the `PdfReader` to open a file but looking at the source code on github it seems like the open method does a whole load of extra "stuff" especially in modify mode which is what I need to use.

Comment: @Matt I understood your idea. But I guess not many people tried that approach and thus you encounter problems that have not yet been identified. Unlikely that the authors will fix it without an MCVE. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example